# ResponseEntity return list objects

Tags: java, spring, rest

In the following code I want to return a list of users from their training using `ResponseEntity`:

```
public Utilisateur initUserByFormation(Integer idFrormation) {
            Utilisateur user = new Utilisaateur() ;
            user = userService.getuserByIdFormation(idFrormation) ;
            return user;
        }
```

and the controller  calls this method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{idFrormation}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity <List<Utilisateur>> test(@PathVariable("idFrormation") Integer idFrormation) {

        List<Utilisateur> utilisateurs = (List<Utilisateur>) userService.initUserByFormation(idFrormation);
        return new ResponseEntity <List<Utilisateur>> (utilisateurs, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
```

However, I get the following error:

> 500 Internal Server Error ERROR Unique id: 1736346060 Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.c3.unedicbase.domain.Demandeur cannot be cast to java.util.List

Can you help me to find the origin of this error?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error

ERROR Unique id: 1736346060

Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.c3.unedicbase.domain.Demandeur cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: Well, looks like you have casting problem. can you show more code? What data is hidden here: `userService.initUserByFormation(idFrormation);` ?

Comment: initUserByFormation this method allows for a query in the database:


public Utilisateur getuserByIdFormation(int idFrormation) {
  return (Utilisateur )demandeurMapper.getDemandeurByIdPrestation(new Integer(idFrormation));

 }

Comment: no, this is `getuser...`. What is about `inituser...`?

Comment: I just dot understand what are you trying to achieve here ,see `Utilisateur initUserByFormation(Integer idFrormation) ` return user object and in controller  method you are doing `List<Utilisateur>  utilisateurs = (List<Utilisateur>) userService.initUserByFormation(idFrormation);`  , you are casting a single user object with list of user which is completely wrong ,did't your IDE shown error !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Might be bit late but will post anyway.

Your method "initUserByFormation" are not returning a list only one object. You will need to convert it you cannot just cast it.

I recommend you change the code to look like the following:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test/{idFrormation}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity <List<Utilisateur>> test(@PathVariable("idFrormation") Integer idFrormation) {

        List<Utilisateur> utilisateurs = List.of(userService.initUserByFormation(idFrormation));
        return new ResponseEntity <List<Utilisateur>> (utilisateurs, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
```

That should resolve your query.